Unable to reach the Preview Tab under XHR tab under Network Tab
I have been trying to write the code to print the preview present under Fetch/XHR tab which is present under Networks Tab. The image is present below-

In this image I want to print on the console after selecting the audio button under captcha.
The link for the website is- https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/
On this site first you have to select the first button on the left "Trade Mark Applications/Registered Mark"
After that select the National/IRDI Number checkbox to go to the desired page

The desired page is-

After inspecting the element, when you will click the audio button below the captcha, you will get to see the captcha in the preview tab under XHR/Fetch tab under Network tab. The captcha code will appear in the preview tab.
I have already created a python code that takes to the desired page.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# switch into the frame context
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "eregoptions")))

# click on the targeted element
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnviewdetails"))).click()

# come out of frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "showframe")))

# click on the targeted element
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rdb_0"))).click()

# come out of frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)

I want to add lines of code that can print the captcha under Preview tab under Fetch/XHR under Network Tab.

We can get the captcha values in 2 ways.

Using seleniumwire
Using requests library

Seleniumwire:

Using seleniumwire, we can track the backend api calls and their responses.
Click on audio button to reveal the captcha.
Iterate a loop over all the requests and get the captcha value

Requests library:

Load the page with selenium as usual and get the SessionId from the main page
Make a POST request by passing SessionId and other necessary header to get the captcha value.

I included both the approaches in the code. Take look and use whichever is comfortable for you.
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
#from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json
import requests

# This method will capture captcha value from the network calls
def get_captcha_details_using_selemiumwire(driver):
    all_req = driver.requests
    for request in all_req:
        url = request.url
        if (url and 'GetCaptcha' in url):
            json_str = request.response.body.decode("utf-8")
            data = json.loads(json_str)
            captcha = data['d']
            print(f"Captcha using seleniumwire: {captcha}")
            return captcha

# This method will make a request with session and get the captcha value
def get_captcha_details_using_requests(session_id):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Cookie': f"ASP.NET_SessionId={session_id}",
        'Origin': 'https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in',
        'Referer': 'https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/Application_View.aspx',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    }

    json_data = {}

    response = requests.post(
        'https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/Viewdetails_Copyright.aspx/GetCaptcha',
        headers=headers,
        json=json_data,
        verify=False,
    )

    data_hash = response.json()
    captcha = data_hash["d"]
    print(f"Captcha using requests library: {captcha}")
    return captcha
    

# Adding seleniumwire options and initializing the driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-http2')
seleniumwire_options = {
        'mitm_http2': False
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)

# Initializing selenium driver
#driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://tmrsearch.ipindia.gov.in/eregister/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Taking session_id from main page to use it in captcha request
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies_list:
    name = cookie["name"]
    if (name and "ASP.NET_SessionId" in name):
        session_id = cookie["value"]
        break
print(f"Session ID: {session_id}")

# switch into the frame context
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "eregoptions")))

# click on the targeted element
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnviewdetails"))).click()

# come out of frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "showframe")))

# click on the targeted element
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rdb_0"))).click()
time.sleep(10)

# click on audio button to reveal captcha in network calls
btn_xpath = "//img[contains(@title,'Captcha Audio')]"
audio_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, btn_xpath)
if audio_btn:
    audio_btn.click()
    print("Clicked on audio button")
    time.sleep(10)

# come out of frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()

captcha = get_captcha_details_using_selemiumwire(driver)

if session_id:
    captcha = get_captcha_details_using_requests(session_id)


Thank you so much, it is working perfectly fine.
